# Six aspects of surrender mentioned in Pancharatra texts?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, agamas, bhakti, pancharatra, sharanagati

Recently while exploring the topic of Devotion or Bhakti , I came across the info. that there are six aspects of surrender to the Lord , mentioned in Pancharatra texts.

So my question is - What are these six aspects of surrender mentioned in the Pancharatra texts? I want the brief description of each and  preferably with direct quotes from original texts.

Comment: I think the possible reason may be: Pancaratra is taught by Vishnu to Narada so, Narada may have established the Pancaratra system, not Ramanujacharya (who born in Pancharatra tradition), though I'm not sure, btw, good question! +1

Comment: @Pandya Thanks. Yes ,I am aware that pancharatra tradition is much older.My guess was also same. But the sentence exactly as it is present in Wikipedia article i have linked. "During the 11th century AD , Shree Ramanuja, a founder of Sri Vaishnava traditions of Vaishnavism had established the Pancaratra system of Vaishnavism for his followers."

Comment: I think Sharanagati tag would be useful here. instead or in addition to bhakti tag

Comment: @Pandya Oh I was not aware of the tag. Thanks i will add that as well as agama tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Prapatti*** (or self-surrender) is an important aspect of ***SrI Vaishnava*** Teachings. According to ***pAncarAtra samhitas*** (*Ahirbudhnya samhitA, LakshmI tantra*), there are six aspects or angas to prapatti:

> आनुकुलस्य संकल्प: प्रतिकूल्यस्य वर्जनम् |
>  रक्षीष्यतीति विश्वासो
>   गोप्त्रुत्ववरणं तथा || [**LakshmI Tantra 17.60**](https://archive.org/stream/LakshmiTantra/Lakshmi%20Tantra%201975%20VKrishnamacharya#page/n119/mode/2up)||
>  आत्मनिक्षेप
>   कार्पण्ये षड्विधा शरणागति:
>
> AnukUlyasya samkalpah prAtikUlyasya varjanam | 
>  rakshishyatIti
>   viSvAso goptRtva varaNam tathA || 
>  AtmA nikshepa kArpaNye
>   shadvidhA SaraNagatih

And here is English Translation of [**LakshmI Tantra**](https://archive.org/stream/LakshmiTantraAPancharatraTextSanjuktaGupta/Lakshmi-Tantra-a-Pancharatra-Text-Sanjukta-Gupta#page/n125) stating 6 components of surrender.

---

- ***nyAsam***: It is the supreme conviction that all efforts by the self, i.e., the individual, directed towards attaining ***SrIman nArAyaNa***, the goal of liberation, are ultimately in vain and will not bear fruits. It is truly supreme and complete, when realising this, the individual willingly and completely surrenders their duty/ownership of protecting themselves directly to ***SrIman nArAyaNa***'s care and the benefits of any and all actions to ***DivyaThampathiyAr*** (i.e., Divine Couple). This is considered the primary limb of prapatti, all the other aspects or angas are in some sense an assistance to this mode of realised being. The obstacle to *nyAsam* is *phalepsA* or attraction to mundane benefits (e.g. siddhis) which should thus be overcome.
- ***kArpaNyam***:  This refers to feeling of absolute humility. It is driven by the realisation drawn from an honest awareness of our pathetic acquisition of karma over and over again lifetime after lifetime. The feeling of *kArpaNya* is expressed expertly by the ***Azhwars*** in the ***Divya Prabhandams***. Thus, reciting (and even listening) to the ***Divya Prabhandams*** leads to burning the vanity that one may
  have accumulated because of ego arising from pride of lineage, learning, wealth and such things. The enemy of *kArpaNya* is the feeling that one is free, independent, and competent to do whatever he likes (*sva-svAtantryAvabodha*). Thus, ***kArpaNya*** or absolute humility is nutured and amplified by contemplating on the fact that without the aid of ***Perumaal***, whatever we undertake on our own is bound to fail.
- ***mahA viSvAsam***: *viSvAsa* is the firm conviction that God will never fail to protect us. Thus, literally, it means "Great Faith" in God as the unitary, compassionate protector and source of perfection of all beings. Thus, *mahA viSvAsam* is capable of eradicating all sins.
- ***goptRtvam***: The deliberate choice of ***bhagavAn SrIman nArAyaNa*** as the sole Protector. Even when it is granted that anyway He is the sole protector, *lakshmI-tantra* points out that what is involved in this anga is
  the conscious and mindful selection of Him, the acknowledgment that we
  need protection, and that He and only He can protect us.
- ***prAtikUlya varjanam***: The realisation that all beings whether Devas or small animals are like oneself. Thus, it involves giving up those actions that are antagonistic to oneself, Creation and God.
- ***AnukUlya sankalpam***: The resolve to do good by all beings. The
  realization that all beings are in actuality the body of God (***shariAtma bhAvam***), and the resolve to live in accordance with the will of ***SrIman nArAyaNa***.

*Source: pAncarAtra Agamam (A brief overview) by SrI narasimhan kRshNamAcAri*

Comment: You can also add direct quotes and shloka from either Laxmi Tantra or Ahirbudhnya samhitA. - https://archive.org/stream/LakshmiTantraAPancharatraTextSanjuktaGupta/Lakshmi-Tantra-a-Pancharatra-Text-Sanjukta-Gupta#page/n125 - Ahirbudhnya samhitA. is also available on archieve.org

Comment: This is link of sanskrit shloka 59-61 - https://archive.org/stream/LakshmiTantra/Lakshmi%20Tantra%201975%20VKrishnamacharya#page/n119/mode/2up

Comment: Fantastic answer!